# Как при наведении на элемент какое-то определенное время и после этого изменить состояние элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотелось реализовать такой эффект для менюшек по ссылке [1](http://osiyo-nur.uz/goodgross/),

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        /*НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        function hover() {
          $(this).children('.li_subitem').toggle();       
        }
        $('.list li').hover(function(){
          setTimeout(hover, 1000);
        });  */
        $('.list li').hover(function(){
          $(this).children('.li_subitem').toggle();       
        });   
        
    });
```

```css
.li_subitem{
      height:200px;
      width:200px;
      background:red;
      display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <head>
      
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Test 1
          <div class="li_subitem">
          
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>Test 2
          <div class="li_subitem">
          
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>Test 3
          <div class="li_subitem">
          
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>Test 4
          <div class="li_subitem">
          
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Дело в том, что ваша функция hover имеет свой this, который не является глобавлным, поэтому нужно записать так:

```
function hover() {
  $(this).children('.li_subitem').toggle();       
}

$('.list li').hover(function(){
  setTimeout(hover.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

С помощью bind делаем доступным переменную this в методе hover.